# How to make factory thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a below factory which will get called from multiple threads. I want to know if it is thread safe or not.

```
public class ClientFactory {
  private Map<TypeName, Provider> holder = new HashMap<>();

  private static class Holder {
    private static final ClientFactory INSTANCE = new ClientFactory();
  }

  public static ClientFactory getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private ClientFactory() {
    holder.put(TypeName.typeA, new DataProvider());
    holder.put(TypeName.typeB, new ProcessProvider());
  }

  public IProcess createNewType(TypeName typeName) {
    Provider provider = holder.get(typeName);
    if (provider == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid typeName is passed");
    }
    IProcess process = new ProcessImpl(typeName.name(), provider);
    return process;
  }
}
```

In my above factory `createNewType` method will be called from multiple threads. I wanted to make it thread safe. Is it thread safe? I am not modifying my `HashMap` once it has been populated in the `ClientFactory` constructor. So I believe it is thread safe since the calls to `get()` on that `HashMap` will be thread safe.

If it is not thread safe then how can I make it thread safe in the most efficient way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: You should declare `holder` to be `final`. Then, the so-called *publication* of the shared `HashaMap` is safe. After the publication all the threads can see it and since the contents of the map do not change, it is expected to behave like an immutable map and hence is thread-safe. The other suggestion to make the map unmodifiable is a good one too.

**Some well-intentioned rants**: Even though you seem to be worrying about thread safety of your factory, there are a few other non-threading related issues with it that you should fix (first).

1. There is no need to use the Holder pattern in such a convoluted way. For instance, what's the need for an inner class just to hold the instance that you immediately construct?
2. Rename `holder` to something more meaningful, e.g. `typeToProvidersMap`. Yes, it is more verbose, but makes the code (much more) readable.
3. Is this is a factory of `Client`s or factory of `Provider`s? If it is the latter, rename the class appropriately. Also, rename the `createNewType()` to `createNewProvider()` because creating a new provider is what the method seems to do.

Even if this is example code, it could still be exemplary.

By 1), I mean that following is better *to begin with*:

```
public class ClientFactory {
  private final Map<TypeName, Provider> typeToProvider = new HashMap<>();
  // constructing the singleton since the construction needn't be lazy
  private static final ClientFactory INSTANCE = new ClientFactory();

  public static ClientFactory getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
  }
// rest is omitted for brevity
}
```

The Holder pattern is to be used when the lazy initialization is desirable with a specific purpose in mind.

Comment: So you are not saying I should not use Holder pattern here? Then what I should be using here then? Any thoughts?

Comment: @user5447339 You basically have only one instance right? In that case simply use a Singleton pattern. I prefer to declare such classes as enumTypes, as it provides Thread safty by default.

Comment: "You should declare holder to be final. Then, the so-called publication of the shared HashaMap is safe". The map is not provided to external classes and is not modified. So using final or not will not make the class thread safe since it is. It is more a way of preventing a case of future erroneous code modification in the class.

Comment: @n247s How can I rewrite this whole thing using singleton pattern? Can you provide an example?

Comment: @user5447339 It is out of the scope of this question to answer it with a singelton pattern design. But the answer on this post provide the basic syntax/pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721115/singleton-pattern-using-enum-version

Comment: @user5447339 No, I just meant that till you demonstrate the need for the Holder pattern, you can use more straightforward constructs.

Comment: @davidxxx See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27254152/what-exactly-does-the-final-keyword-guarantee-regarding-concurrency

Comment: @Kedar Mhaswade It doesn't answer to what I said. Can you point out where the code of the OP is not thread safe ?

Comment: All I am saying is that without `final` the map may not be _seen_ by all the threads.

Answer (score -1):

If your HashMap isn't modified, than the Factory class is Thread safe. Though the problems may start when using the Objects in the map (as they are not Thread safe, even if the Map implementation would be Thread-safe).

So make sure the Provider implementations are Thread safe, or lock the whole Provider instance on acces (which may notbe the best solution).