# Does Kotlin val give the same visibility guarantees as java final?

Tags: java, kotlin, concurrency, final, java-memory-model

I have  a class like this:

```
class MyClass {
    private val myLock = ReentrantLock()
    ...
}
```

In java I would make this field final to provide memory guarantees:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27254652/2674303

Does `val` provides the same guarantees ?

Comment: The [Kotlin spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/concurrency.html#concurrency) explicitly doesn't specify anything about how concurrency works, so this is probably platform dependent. I'm not sure how different platforms handle it.

Comment: @user2357112 but how can I write concurrent code using Kotlin at this case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, at least on Kotlin/JVM. For other platforms, probably not.

While I couldn't find authoritative documentation on this (The Kotlin/JVM spec still hasn't been written), a private `val` declared in the way your example does, compiles to a `final` field in bytecode. You can see this by inspecting the .class file. It is unlikely that they will change this to generate a non-`final` field in the future, because as you pointed out, `final` fields have certain guarantees, and removing `final` will be a breaking change.

Of course, if the `val` doesn't have a backing field, like `val x get() = 1`, then no field is generated.